# Duplicate block django 1.3?

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using django cms 2.2 and django 1.3. I want to automatically generate meta descriptions based on the first 200 characters of my 'content' block.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably extend the "get_placeholder_content" method from cms_tags.py in django-cms to get the placeholder content for the current page.

From there, you can parse the content, generate your meta tags and output them to the context.